# How to install PIL with zlip and jpg support in centos with pip python

Tags: python, centos, pip

When i install `pip install PIL` then i get this

```
   *** TKINTER support not available
    *** JPEG support not available
    *** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not available
    *** FREETYPE2 support not available
    *** LITTLECMS support not available
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have all the libraries and i tried this as well

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libz.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
```

how can i install all of the above with pip on centos

Comment: Make sure the libs you need are in the search path.

Comment: How did you install python?  In my experience with package managers, sometimes you need to explicitly install `tkinter`.  I think it's `sudo apt-get install python-tk` on Ubuntu -- Don't know about centos though.  (and this only addresses 1 of your dependency issues ...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the required headers from the corresponding libraries: `libjpeg`, `libpng`, and others.

Usually, you will need the `dev` packages for those libraries to have the headers.

---

Nevertheless, installing `PIL` is usually pretty complicated as it often fails to detect the libraries. You should do `pip install pillow` instead. `pillow` is an installer for `PIL`, which finds libraries more easily.

Comment: I have those so installed but how can PIL find them

Comment: @user1914461 Did you try installing `pillow` as I suggested?

Comment: Thanks buddy , i first removed PIL and pillow and then again installed pillow only and everthing is ok now , thanks

Comment: @user1914461 : )